# How to access argc/argv in iOS application?

Tags: ios5, command-line-arguments

I have to run my iOS app in simulator, providing some additional info on launch.

However, I can't find a way to access `argc/argv` in my app. I thought I can find these somewhere in UIApplication, but I can't. Then I've checked `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`, but `launchOptions` was nil.

Is there a way to get an access to command-line arguments in iOS application?

Comment: Why.. would you want to?  There's no way to give arguments from an actual phone... if you want it for debugging purposes, use the `#ifset DEBUG` flags...

Comment: This app will never be launched on real device, it's for testing purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Save values in either a `plist` which you read every startup, or in the `NSUserDefaults` dictionary from a previous run, which you access at startup.

If it *must* be external only, and argument-based only, set the arguments array from `NSProcessInfo`:

```
NSArray *arguments = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments];
```

Comment: NSProcessInfo is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the launch option is used as follow:

**launchOptions**

> A dictionary indicating the reason the application was launched (if
>   any). The contents of this dictionary may be empty in situations where
>   the user launched the application directly. See “Launch Options Keys”
>   in [UIApplication Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728) for descriptions of these keys.

See [UIApplicationDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3adidFinishLaunchingWithOptions%3a) documentation